# How to retrieve tweets of user and his/her followers under a certain hashtag using Twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to build a `twitter4j` application that creates a small twitter network, actually. Here is my sample code snippet:

```html
//Monitoring hashtags
Query query = new Query("#anger"); 
query.setCount(100); //get 100 tweets
query.setSince("2010-01-01");
QueryResult result;  
try { 
     result = twitter.search(query);
     for (Status status : result.getTweets()) 
     {
      if (status.getText() != null)
      {
             // Getting followers list of a given user
             ArrayList<User> followers = getFollowers(status.getUser().getScreenName());
           for (User user : followers) 
    {
                    if (status.getUser().getScreenName().contains(user.getScreenName()))
      {
                      System.out.println(status.getUser().getScreenName());
      }
           }          
       }
      }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

I think that this code should print `existence(names)` of the followers of users under "#anger" hashtag. However, when I run this code, it violates the api 1.1 rate limits with an exception (message - Rate limit exceeded, code - 88). How can I overcome this issue?

Here is also my `getFollowers()` method:

```html
// Getting followers list of a given user
public static ArrayList<User> getFollowers (String usname)
{
  Twitter twitter = initTwitter();
  String username = usname;
  ArrayList<User> followers = new ArrayList<User>();
  long nextCursor = -1;
  do  {
    PagableResponseList<User> usersResponse;
    try 
    {
      usersResponse = twitter.getFollowersList(username, nextCursor);
   nextCursor = usersResponse.getNextCursor();
   followers.addAll(usersResponse);
    } 
 catch (TwitterException e) 
 {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }    
   } while (nextCursor > 0);

return followers; 
}
```

Comment: Probably it is from `getFollowers` method. Can you post that?

Comment: I have added getFollowers() method into my post @RamananR. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limit for calling getFollowers() is:

```
Requests / 15-min window (user auth): 15
Requests / 15-min window (app auth): 30
```

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

Since you are calling getFollowers() more than this from `for (Status status : result.getTweets())` you are getting rate limit error.

Check rate limits here:

```
    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) 
     {
         if (status.getText() != null)
         {
             // Getting followers list of a given user
             ArrayList<User> followers = getFollowers(status.getUser().getScreenName());
             // Here, Check if you rate limit has been exceeded. 
             // If so, wait till limit is over and then continue
              .....
         }
     }
```